# Dynamically move and edit text?

Tags: scripts

I've created a LaTeX document to track my goals and weekly/daily to-do's. I have labels for the goals and weekly tasks that I reference in the daily tasks. Here is what I am hoping to automate with either LaTeX or an external script:

1. On the next day, move the `enumerate` list under the `Today` subsection to the archive subsection and add text above it to mark yesterday's date.
2. At the end of the week, do the same as (1) for the `Week` `enumerate` list AND append the date to labels in this list and corresponding references.
3. When I complete a goal, do the same as (2).

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Let me know if you need more information. I'm not sure if it can be done straight through LaTeX or if I will need to use a scripting language. I could do this manually of course, but I'm trying to maximize productivity.

Comment: Using LaTeX for to-do list seems like the opposite of *maximizing* productivity. I'd rather suggest [orgmode](https://orgmode.org) instead

Comment: Could you provide a 'before' and 'after' example that details how you'd like things to look?